# Retrieve the latest or the last value of a column in a dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset

The below code gives the first row.. but i need to get the latest or the last row  updated. Please help

```
 Dim dt As DateTime = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Columnname")
```

Comment: "last" is an irrelevant term with db data since you have no idea how it is stored and depending on your WHERE clause (or lack thereof) the same data can be returned to you on a different order.  You should also turn on Option Strict.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Rows.Count property as shown in other answer or just let do that to Linq

```
Dim row = ds.Tables(0).AsEnumerable().Last()
Dim dt As DateTime = row.Field(Of DateTime)("ColumnName")
```

Of course this works for the last row of the table. This doesn't mean something like the last (more recent) value for the "ColumnName". If this is your intention then you need to "Sort" the datatable or better ask the source (a database ? ) of the rows to sort it.

If you are not able to change the data loading query to have it sorted directly from the database engine then you could reach (in code) the latest row ordered by "ColumnName" using something like this

```
' Create a dataview from the datatable, with no filter and ordered by ColumnName
Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(ds.Tables(0), "", "ColumnName ASC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
dt = dv.Cast(Of DataRowView).Last().Row.Field(Of DateTime)("Column")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ds.Tables(x).Rows.Count-1`

```
Dim dt As DateTime = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("Columnname")
```

Comment: @Sandy777 If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept an answer or detail how you managed to solve your problem.

Comment: Dim dt As DateTime = ds.Tables(0).Rows(ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1)("Columnname")    this line works fine to get the latest row

Comment: @Sandy777 I'm glad that my answer helped you. Could you accept it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in ?